# MPI Error - What is happening?

Tags: arrays, malloc, mpi, recv

This can be a very stupid question, but I can't see my mistake in this code... The output is wrong, rank 1 prints:

3.000000 - 3.000000 - 3.000000 - 3.000000 - 3.000000 -
3.000000 - 3.000000 - 3.000000 - 3.000000 - 3.000000 -
 
3.000000 - 3.000000 - 3.000000 - 3.000000 - 3.000000 -
3.000000 - 3.000000 - 3.000000 - 3.000000 - 3.000000 -
 
3.000000 - 0.000000 - 0.000000 - 0.000000 - 0.000000 -

I need to use MPI_Recv instead Bcast... But what is going on? =/ It is my malloc? Or can't I send an entire matrix using MPI_Recv? Why the entire array does not go to another process?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mpi.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int rank, size;
    int lines, cols;
    int i, j;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    MPI_Status status;

    lines = 5;
    cols = 5;

    if(rank == 0){
        double** array = (double**) malloc(lines*sizeof(double*));
        for(i=0; i<lines; i++)
            array[i] = (double*) malloc(cols*sizeof(double));

        for(i=0; i<lines; i++)
            for(j=0; j<cols; j++)
                    array[i][j] = 3;

        for(i=0; i<lines; i++){
            for(j=0; j<cols; j++)
                    printf("%f - ", array[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
        }

        MPI_Send(&array[0][0], lines*cols, MPI_DOUBLE, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    else{
        double** arrayNew = (double**)malloc(lines*sizeof(double*));
        for (i=0; i<lines; i++)
                arrayNew[i] = (double*) malloc(cols*sizeof(double));

        MPI_Recv(&arrayNew[0][0], lines*cols, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

        for(i=0; i<lines; i++){
                for(j=0; j<cols; j++)
                        printf("%f - ", arrayNew[i][j]);
                printf("\n");
        }
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This comes up all the time, and the issue is C and multidimensional arrays.

The problem is that this line

```
    MPI_Send(&array[0][0], lines*cols, MPI_DOUBLE, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

is telling MPI to send `lines*cols` doubles starting from position `&(array[0][0])`, and similarly this line

```
    MPI_Recv(&arrayNew[0][0], lines*cols, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
```

is telling MPI to receive `lines*cols` doubles into memory starting from from position `&(array[0][0])`.   But  this allocation:

```
    double** arrayNew = (double**)malloc(lines*sizeof(double*));
    for (i=0; i<lines; i++)
            arrayNew[i] = (double*) malloc(cols*sizeof(double));
```

doesn't make a contiguous array of `lines*cols` doubles; it makes `lines` arrays of `cols` doubles, and those lines could be scattered all over memory.  You need to do something like:

```
    double** array = (double**) malloc(lines*sizeof(double*));
    array[0] = (double *)malloc(lines*cols*sizeof(double));
    for(i=1; i<lines; i++)
        array[i] = &(array[0][i*cols]);

    /* ... */

    free(array[0]);
    free(array);
```

to allocate and free a contiguous `lines*cols` block of memory that you can send from and receive into.

Comment: Oh!!! Yes, it's true!! I didn't remember that, because I'm used to create with []... Perfect answer!!

Thank you a lot!!! =D